# Given a solution of a complex cubic, find the other two.

Tags: complex-analysis

Given that you know one of the solutions of

$$z^3+(6+5i)z+5-5i=0$$

is $z=1-3i$, find the other two.

---

So is there a quicker way of finding the solutions to this other than making a guess or equating coefficients?

I have tried

\begin{align}(z-(1-3i))(z-a)(z-b) &=  (z-(1-3i))(z^2-(a+b)z + ab) \\
&= z^3 - (a+b)z^2+abz-(1-3i)z^2+(1-3i)(a+b)z-ab(1-3i) \\
&= z^3 - (1-3i+a+b)z^2+[ab+(a+b)(1-3i)]z-ab(1-3i)\end{align}

\begin{align}
&\implies 1-3i+a+b=0 \implies a+b= -1+3i\\
&\implies ab(1-3i) = 5-5i \implies ab = (5-5i)/(1-3i) = 2+i
\end{align}

So we have a system of equations to solve for $a$ and $b$.

$$a(-1+3i-a) - 2 - i = 0$$

$$\implies -a^2 + (-1+3i)a - 2 - i=0$$

$$\implies a^2 + (1-3i)a + 2 + i=0$$

\begin{align}
\implies a &= \frac{-1+3i\pm \sqrt{(1-3i)^2-4(2+i)}}{2}\\
&= \frac{-1+3i\pm \sqrt{(1-3i)^2-4(2+i)}}{2}\\
&= \frac{-1+3i\pm \sqrt{-16-10i}}{2}\\
\end{align}

Now I think I've definitely done something wrong because the other solutions are $i$ and $-1+2i$. Additionally this is an exam question worth only a few marks so clearly it's not expected to be a very long question however this has taken ages to work out. Is there a faster way to do this without guessing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $(z-1+3i)$ is a factor of $z^3+(6+5i)z+5-5i$ using long division $(z^3+(6+5i)z+5-5i)/(z-1+3i)=z^2+(1-3i)z+(-2-i)$ whose roots can be seen by vieta's formulas you can easily see roots are $i$ and $2i-1$